# Consistent Format for Time Intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called T_Int and the data looks like:

```
Interval
0
30
100
130
200
230
---
---
2300
2330
```

i want the values to be consistent. My output should be like this:

```
Interval
0000
0030
0100
0130
---
---
2300
2330
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Is `interval` character or numeric?

Comment: @MarkBannister It's Numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I wish SQL Server had `to_char()` like Oracle and Postgres.

Here is one way:

```
select right(replicate('0', 4)+cast(Interval as varchar(255)), 4)
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has `SELECT FORMAT(Interval, '0000') ...` if ANSI doesn't support something, I'd rather align with .NET than Oracle/Postgres.